# C++ xml (should I use msxml6?, I installed msxml6 but not see where it is)

Tags: c++, xml, msxml6

I have couple of questions regarding to c++ xml. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

1. Should I use msxml6.dll for my c++ xml parsing?
2. I have installed the msxml6.dll, however, I could not find where it is installed. Should see a new directory called MSXML 6.0 under C:\Program Files (x86)\ or C:\Program Files\? But I did not see any. However, I see msxml6.dll in C:\Windows\System32.
3. How I add reference to the msxml6.dll in my c++ project?

Thanks,
ZAJ,

Comment: MSXML is COM based. You need to use `CoCreateInstance` to access it's class implementations. Simply adding a reference to it in your project is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the more lightweight XML library -- [tinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/)

The MSXML is a COM-server. You can include it using the [import directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Also you can use the MSXML.h file that must be included in the MSXML SDK. To use any COM-server you should call two functions: [CoInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CoCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for recommending the tinyXML. I will look into this. It may be all I need since I only have a very small xml file to be parsed.